# Autoclick JavaScript link in Table

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, click, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

So I've got this HTML Table as follows:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="link1"></td>
        <td><a href=link2"></td>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="link3"></td>
        <td><a href=link4"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

It has many more rows than this but this is just a section for the purpose of my question. I know Javascript uses .click to click on links, but I am wondering if there is any way to select the link in the first row first column, because on different web pages the first link in the first column will be different than the one on this page. If this is possible how do I do so? Thank you so much. I looked into this trying to find the answer on my own and I didn't find one. If it helps, I am using Tampermonkey to run the script. Thank you for your help!

Lucy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return you first link from the table

```
document.querySelector('table a')
```

if you want first link from the webpage then use

```
document.querySelector('a')
```

If you want to click on it then

```
document.querySelector('table a').click()
```

Or if you want to open in different window then,

```
window.open(document.querySelector('table a').href)

document.querySelector('#profile_creatures table a').click()
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I am using: window.open(cument.querySelector('table a'),"_self");
Should that work? Or am I missing something. Do I need to use .click()?

Comment: @TurtleBo document.querySelector('table a').click() will do

Comment: Thank you! That is working but the issue is that there are multiple tables on the page. Unfortunately none of them have ID's. is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @TurtleBo: is there any way to find which table could have links? or which kind of link you are looking for? or something, I can create a selctor accordingly

Comment: They do actually have IDs of sort. The first one has actually has <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="656" id="p_cover">, and the table I want has <div id="profile_creatures"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

Comment: But if that doesn't work, the link type I need is of form http://eggcave.com/egg/*, but so is the link in the other table. Both of the tables have links

Comment: @TurtleBo : try, window.open(document.querySelector('#profile_creatures table a').href)

Comment: Hmm it seems to be trying to open something but chrome is blocking it and saying popup blocked. Is this opening in a new window? How to open in same window? Nevermind I used "_self" and that worked! THank you!

Comment: document.querySelector('#profile_creatures table a').click()

Comment: Yes! Sorry. I am working on completeing the entire script so it does what I want. THank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using JQuery

```
var attribute = $('td a:first').attr('href');
console.log(attribute);
```

Comment: I know what the problem is. There is more than one table on the page, but they don't have ID's or anything. Is there any way for me to fix this?

Comment: Oh wait. The first one has <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="656" id="p_cover">, and the table I want has <div id="profile_creatures"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">